# javascript get the last duplicate value index javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array to be like this 
`var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`.
so it contains duplicate values. In here last index value of 
'0' is '3',
'1' is '4',
'2' is '5',
'3' is '13',
 and so on.

 And i counted total duplicate values

```
var counts = {};
arr.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; })
```

but i want to know last duplicate value index only. please help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: And how do you want the results?

Comment: i want the result in an array.

Comment: Seeing as `counts` is an object, there is no "last", as there is no order

Comment: Will the array always be sorted?

Comment: yes it always sorted.

Comment: @adeneo `count` is the output object, array `arr` is the input.

Comment: Will the array always have values grouped together (ie. [0,0,1,1,2,2]) or can they be scattered (ie. [0,1,2,0,1,2])?

Comment: @william.taylor.09 if it scattered we can just sort and grouped together. that is not a problem

Comment: @htoniv Well, sorting it first kind of defeats the purpose of finding an index, doesn't it?

Comment: This just smells like an X/Y problem, also, you actually want the non-duplicate values as well, like `1`, so all you really would need is `arr.lastIndexOf()` to check any value, why keep an object ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5];
var existingItems = {};

arr.forEach(function(value, index) {
    existingItems[value] = index;
});

console.log(existingItems);
```

Comment: @adeneo, nope. It uses the second parameter of `forEach`, which is the index, instead of the first one, which is the value. It also overwrites each previous index with the new index, thus at the end it will contain the last index. +1 @Shaun, we think alike :)

Comment: @nem - I finally got the point, it just seemed so strange I got confused

Comment: I like this solution. Also works for unsorted arrays! +1

Answer (score 1):

Simple loop and check to see if next index is different

```
var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
var indexes = arr.reduce(function(result, cur, ind, arr){
   if (ind+1===arr.length || cur != arr[ind+1]) {  //check to see if last or different
       result.push(ind);  //if different, store the index
   }
   return result;
},[]);
console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: This is probably the only correct answer, since OP said he wants an array. Specially since he doesn't specify anything about how the array should look.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can do is check if a value is a duplicate (`count > 1`) and then use the second parameter of `forEach` which is the index to remember it. Something like:

```js
var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5];
var counts = {};
var indexes = {};
arr.forEach(function(x, idx) {
  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;
  if(counts[x] > 1) { indexes[x] = idx; } // check if a value is a duplicate and update its index
});

// logs the last index of all duplicate values
console.log(indexes); // {0: 3, 3: 13, 4: 15, 5: 22}
```

If you want the last index of **all values**, not just duplicates, you can omit the `count > 1` check:

```js
var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5];
var counts = {};
var indexes = {};
arr.forEach(function(x, idx) {
  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;
  indexes[x] = idx; // update value index
});

// logs the last index of all values
console.log(indexes); // {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 13, 4: 15, 5: 22}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) comes in handy here:

```
var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5];

var out = {};

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  if(!out.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    out[item] = arr.lastIndexOf(item);
  }
});

console.log(out); // Object {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 13, 4: 15, 5: 22}
```

This will also work for unsorted input arrays.

Comment: This might be an overkill considering that `lastIndexOf` performs a loop over the array for each element, thus O(N^2), while this can be done in O(N).

Comment: @nem I agree. However, depending on the situation, the more readable and maintainable code may be worth the (minor) performance penalty. Also, this way we do not rely on the premise that the array is sorted.

Comment: Going from O(N) to O(N^2) is certainly not a minor performance penalty. Also, you already have the index passed into `forEach`, so yo can just use it instead of calling `lastIndexOf`, hence readability as well ^_^.

Comment: I just saw Shaun's solution and I like it better than mine. Note though that `lastIndexOf` will only be called once per unique item, not once per element of `arr`, which makes it a little less bad... :-)